# Matrix multiplication using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to multiply a 2x3 matrix and a 3x2 matrix using VBA. However, I am not getting the expected output. For example, the two matrices and the output I get are: 
[input matrices and the output I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHYmy.png)

[image]
This is the wrong output but I do not understand how I can fix it to get the correct output. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub MatrixMult2()

Dim inp1(1, 2) As Integer
Dim inp2(2, 1) As Integer

Dim out(1, 1) As Integer

For j = 0 To 1
For i = 0 To 1

    inp1(i, j) = Range("A28").Cells(i + 1, j + 2)
    inp2(i, j) = Range("E28").Cells(i + 2, j + 1)

Next i
Next j


Dim temp As Integer

For a = 0 To 1
    For b = 0 To 1
        For c = 0 To 2

            temp = temp + inp1(a, c) * inp2(c, b)

        Next c
        out(a, b) = temp
        temp = 0
    Next b
Next a

For j = 0 To 1
For i = 0 To 1
Range("H28").Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = out(i, j)
Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: How *to multiply a 2x3 matrix and a 3x2 matrix*? How many results will there be? If each value in the first matrix were multiplied with each value of the second the output could be just one, or it could be 36.

Comment: Multiplication of matrix A and B is well defined.

Comment: Then explain it to me lah.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: And there is no need to re-programm this, you can use [MMULT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: @Storax Thank you. Now I'll look at MMULT :-)

Comment: You can assign Ranges to Arrays (and vice-versa) directly through VBA, e.g. `inp1 = Range("A28:C29").Value` and `inp2 = Range("E28:F30").Value` for input, and `Range("H28:I29").Value = out` - this will fix the fact that your first look *only assigns the top-left 2-by-2 values* — you are leaving the third row/column in each matrix/array as 0

Answer (score 2):

## The Matrix

Since my knowledge about matrices doesn't extend beyond the three sentences in the first image, use any of it with caution.

[Matrix Multiplication (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

### Excel - `MMULT`

**Sheet1**

For the left example copy the following formula into cell `H2`:

```
=MMULT(A2:C3,E2:F4)
```

Now select cell `H2` and extend the range to `I3` getting range `H2:I3` selected with cell `H2` active (its color is `white` while the other cells are `gray`). Click into the formula bar and confirm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. When you look in the formula bar, each of the four cells (visually) have the same formula:

```
{=MMULT(A2:C3,E2:F4)}
```

where the braces (`{` and `}`) only indicate that this is an array formula. The braces have been automatically added, do not try to add them manually.

For the right example copy the following formula into cell `R7`:

```
=MMULT(N2:P5,R2:V4)
```

Now select cell `R7` and extend the range to `V10` getting range `R7:V10` selected with cell `R7` active (its color is `white` while the other cells are `gray`). Click into the formula bar and confirm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. When you look in the formula bar, each of the twenty cells (visually) have the same formula:

```
{=MMULT(N2:P5,R2:V4)}
```

where the braces (`{` and `}`) only indicate that this is an array formula. The braces have been automatically added, do not try to add them manually.

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet2**

According to your code, you can use the following formula in cell `H28`:

```
=MMULT(A28:C29,E28:F30)
```

Now select cell `H28` and extend the range to `I29` getting range `H28:I29` selected with cell `H28` active (its color is `white` while the other cells are `gray`). Click into the formula bar and confirm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. When you look in the formula bar, each of the four cells (visually) have the same formula:

```
{=MMULT(A28:C29,E28:F30)}
```

where the braces (`{` and `}`) only indicate that this is an array formula. The braces have been automatically added, do not try to add them manually.

[image: Sheet2]

### VBA

Adjust the constants as you see fit.

```
Option Explicit

' The Sub Solutions

' Sub Version (No Functions Used)
Sub writeMatrixProductSub()

    Const Sheet As String = "Sheet2"
    Const rngM1 As String = "A28:C29"
    Const rngM2 As String = "E28:F30"
    Const celMP As String = "H28"

    Dim M1, M2, MP, Row1 As Long, Col1Row2 As Long, Col2 As Long, Curr As Double

    ' Read from worksheet and write to arrays.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet)
        M1 = .Range(rngM1)
        M2 = .Range(rngM2)
    End With

    ' Calculate in arrays.
    If UBound(M1, 2) <> UBound(M2) Then Exit Sub
    ReDim MP(1 To UBound(M1), 1 To UBound(M2, 2))
    For Col2 = 1 To UBound(M2, 2)
        For Row1 = 1 To UBound(M1)
            For Col1Row2 = 1 To UBound(M1, 2)
                Curr = Curr + M1(Row1, Col1Row2) * M2(Col1Row2, Col2)
            Next Col1Row2
            MP(Row1, Col2) = Curr: Curr = 0
        Next Row1
    Next Col2

    ' Check values of Matrix Product in Immediate window.
'    For Row1 = 1 To UBound(MP)
'        For Col1Row2 = 1 To UBound(MP, 2)
'            Debug.Print MP(Row1, Col1Row2)
'        Next
'    Next

    ' Write to worksheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet)
        .Range(celMP).Resize(UBound(MP), UBound(MP, 2)) = MP
    End With

End Sub

' Sub Version Using "WorksheetFunction.MMult" with qualified worksheet
Sub writeMatrixProductMMultSubQualify()
    Const Sheet As String = "Sheet2"
    Const rngM1 As String = "A28:C29"
    Const rngM2 As String = "E28:F30"
    Const celMP As String = "H28"
    Dim M1, M2, MP
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet)
        M1 = .Range(rngM1)
        M2 = .Range(rngM2)
        If UBound(M1, 2) <> UBound(M2) Then Exit Sub
        ReDim MP(1 To UBound(M1), 1 To UBound(M2, 2))
        MP = WorksheetFunction.MMult(M1, M2)
        .Range(celMP).Resize(UBound(MP), UBound(MP, 2)) = MP
    End With
End Sub

' Sub Version Using "WorksheetFunction.MMult"
Sub writeMatrixProductMMultSub()
    Const rngM1 As String = "A28:C29"
    Const rngM2 As String = "E28:F30"
    Const celMP As String = "H28"
    Dim M1, M2, MP
    M1 = Range(rngM1)
    M2 = Range(rngM2)
    If UBound(M1, 2) <> UBound(M2) Then Exit Sub
    ReDim MP(1 To UBound(M1), 1 To UBound(M2, 2))
    MP = WorksheetFunction.MMult(M1, M2)
    Range(celMP).Resize(UBound(MP), UBound(MP, 2)) = MP
End Sub

' The Function Solutions

'  Sub Using "writeMatrixProduct" and "getMatrixProduct1"
Sub testMatrixProductSimple()
    Const rngM1 As String = "A28:C29"
    Const rngM2 As String = "E28:F30"
    Const celMP As String = "H28"
    writeMatrixProduct Range(rngM1), Range(rngM2), Range(celMP)
End Sub

'  Sub Using "writeMatrixProduct" and "getMatrixProduct1" with Checking
Sub testMatrixProductCheck()
    Const rngM1 As String = "A28:C29"
    Const rngM2 As String = "E28:F30"
    Const celMP As String = "H28"
    Dim Success As Boolean
    Success = writeMatrixProduct(Range(rngM1), Range(rngM2), Range(celMP))
    If Success Then
        MsgBox "Write was successful.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Write was unsuccessful. Nothing written.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

' The Functions

' Remarks:      2D 1-based is convenient for operating in ranges.

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Using the "getMatrixProduct1" function, writes the matrix      '
'               product of two matrices contained in ranges to another range.  '
' Returns:      A boolean indicating if the operation was successful.          '
' Remarks:      The resulting range is specified only by its first cell.       '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function writeMatrixProduct(Matrix1 As Range, Matrix2 As Range, _
  MatrixProductFirstCell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim M1, M2, MP
    On Error GoTo handleError
    M1 = Matrix1: M2 = Matrix2
    MP = getMatrixProduct1(M1, M2)
    If Not IsArray(MP) Then Exit Function
    MatrixProductFirstCell.Resize(UBound(MP), UBound(MP, 2)) = MP
    writeMatrixProduct = True
exitProcedure:
Exit Function
handleError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume exitProcedure
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a 2D 1-based array containing the matrix product       '
'               of two matrices contained in 2D 1-based arrays.                '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getMatrixProduct1(Matrix1 As Variant, Matrix2 As Variant) As Variant
    If UBound(Matrix1, 2) <> UBound(Matrix2) Then Exit Function
    Dim MP, Row1 As Long, Col1Row2 As Long, Col2 As Long, Curr As Double
    ReDim MP(1 To UBound(Matrix1), 1 To UBound(Matrix2, 2))
    For Col2 = 1 To UBound(Matrix2, 2)
        For Row1 = 1 To UBound(Matrix1)
            For Col1Row2 = 1 To UBound(Matrix1, 2)
                Curr = Curr + Matrix1(Row1, Col1Row2) * Matrix2(Col1Row2, Col2)
            Next Col1Row2
            MP(Row1, Col2) = Curr: Curr = 0
        Next Row1
    Next Col2
    getMatrixProduct1 = MP
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a 2D 1-based array containing the matrix product       '
'               of two matrices contained in 2D 1-based arrays.                '
' Remarks:      While testing it turned out to be over 10 times slower than    '
'               the "getMatrixProduct1" function (needs to be verified).       '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getMatrixProduct1M(Matrix1 As Variant, Matrix2 As Variant) As Variant
    If UBound(Matrix1, 2) <> UBound(Matrix2) Then Exit Function
    Dim MP: ReDim MP(1 To UBound(Matrix1), 1 To UBound(Matrix2, 2))
    MP = WorksheetFunction.MMult(Matrix1, Matrix2): getMatrixProduct1M = MP
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MatrixMult2()
    Dim inp1(1, 2) As Integer
    Dim inp2(2, 1) As Integer
    Dim out(1, 1) As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer

    ' Initialize temp to 0
    temp = 0

    ' Populate inp1 and inp2 matrices
    For j = 0 To 2
        For i = 0 To 1
            inp1(i, j) = Range("A28").Cells(i + 1, j + 2).Value
            inp2(j, i) = Range("E28").Cells(j + 2, i + 1).Value
        Next i
    Next j

    ' Perform matrix multiplication
    For a = 0 To 1
        For b = 0 To 1
            For c = 0 To 2
                temp = temp + inp1(a, c) * inp2(c, b)
            Next c
            out(a, b) = temp
            temp = 0
        Next b
    Next a

    ' Write the result to Range("H28")
    For j = 0 To 1
        For i = 0 To 1
            Range("H28").Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = out(i, j)
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In matrix multiplication, a 2x3 matrix times a 3x2 matrix will return a 2x2 matrix.

In general, for two matrices (A x B) matrix-multiplied by (B x C) returns (A x C), where the # columns in matrix 1 (the value B) must equal the number of rows in matrix 2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).